# Publish .loadtest Results on TFS

Tags: tfs, mstest, load-testing, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using a TFS Release to execute .loadtests written in Visual Studio.
I can execute the tests fine using MSTest, this produces the expected .trx file.

What I want is to be able to see the test results within TFS, I have tried using the 'Publish Test Results' task but have experienced issues.

The issue encountered was an `Object not set to an instance of an object`

Upon analysing the powershell scripts that 'Publish Test Results' task executes, from what I can see, the only results that are read in the TrxResultReader are from 'WebTest' and 'UnitTest'.

Has anyone managed to publish the results of a **loadtest** within TFS?

Comment: Part of the problem is: What are the results of a load test"? The actual results are stored in an SQL database and it can be analyzed in various ways to produce various graphs and tables etc. The results can include data from many performance counters, so what exactly would you want to store? One option is to `Export` the results as a ".ltrar" file (which can be compressed) and then import that file into TFS. I am not aware of any automated way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

For TFS Publish Test Results task. This task supports popular test result formats including JUnit, NUnit 2, NUnit 3, Visual Studio Test (TRX), and xUnit 2. If you use the built-in tasks such as Visual Studio Test to run tests, results are automatically published and you do not need a separate publish test results task.

Based on the powershell script behind the build task, it use TestRunner. Since Vstest cannot run load test, it cannot publish load test result too. Take a look at below similar question:

> [Publish Test Results task fail when trying to publish a loadtest](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/523950f1-d6f1-4c49-b276-485ac41f80fe/publish-test-results-task-fail-when-trying-to-publish-a-loadtest?forum=tfsbuild)
>
> It is not possible to use mstest to publish test results to build
>   made by a vNext. mstest can not identify the correct buildnummer /
>   buildid. Our solution will probably be that we store the *.trx file a
>   artifact. An other solution is to use a xaml build to perform
>   performance tests.